How to Push Phishing Email Logs from Mail Server to Wazuh?
I'm working on integrating phishing email detection logs from our mail server into Wazuh. We have detection rules in place but need guidance on how to forward these logs to Wazuh for monitoring and alerting.
Is there a way to send phishing email logs from our mail server to Wazuh? We have detection rules but don't know how to transfer the logs to Wazuh.....
